# In FPA, are ILFs and EIFs really only Files or Databases?

Tags: function-points

In FPA, are ILFs and EIFs really only Files or Databases - or can they be internal data structures?

I have not been able to determine how to apply FPA to complex algorithms or number crunching (such as signal processing) so I am wondering where internal data structures (that are computed only at runtime) are accounted for in FPA.  Could such processing (and data) be accounted for in the External Output (EO)?

Thanks gang.

Answer (score 0):

Based on various sources, it does seem that ILFs and EIFs are limited to physical files or databases vs. internal data structures.  FPA seems oriented toward MIS type applications.